# Error connecting to PostgreSQL from Server Explorer - Could not load file or assembly, Version=4.0.4.1 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe'

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, npgsql

I am trying to connect PostgreSQL from .net core Server Explorer using Npgsql 4.1.1. But it is throwing exception Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe'.

I tried installing earlier version of Npgsql but, still the same exception.

Comment: I face the same problem and tried the same solutions but without success:
The error occurred:

        Type:       CompatibilityException
        Message:    Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' ou uma de suas dependências. A definição do manifesto do assembly localizado não corresponde à referência do assembly. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: After uninstalling 4.1.1 and installing 4.0.9 (the 4.1.0 release tag does not have an MSI asset), I was able to successfully connect.